# SSRS Date Parameter Formatting Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I am using SSRS 2019 and have an issue with date formats.  I have a report that takes 2 date parameters using the report date picker, when I run the report through visual studio 2019 the report date picker dates are in the right format.  When I upload it to my SSRS portal and run the same report and pick the dates it displays it MM-DD-YYYY rather than DD-MM-YYYY though it still works and generates the report.  What I don't want to do is confuse users.  I have checked all the region settings on my browsers as well as my server and all are set to English, I have the language in my report set to "en-UK".  What I have noticed though is when I go to Manage the report through the portal and look at the changed and created dates they are also in the wrong format.  This seems to be either an issue with my portal or server setting but I am not sure where else I can change this setting.

I thought I had managed to fix my issue with dates but it appears not and I may just have confused myself with too many changes.

My outstanding issue is, if I open up the report builder directly on the server the date format in the parameter box once you have clicked the calendar is as expected and works.  If I run the report as normal on the reporting portal and click the date in calendar it sets it to MM-DD-YYYY.  My server language setting is British English and my Browser is also set the same, what else could be changing the format?

Comment: I have changed the format of the searching date in the dataset to match the variable DD-MM-YYYY this now returns the data fine in the portal.  The only issue there seems to be is the report builder does not show the correct records, its like it still wants the parameter in the old format MM-DD-YYYY.  As I have download the reportbuilder of the report direct from the portal I would of thought this was using the same format as I have applied to the site by editing the ReportViewer.aspx.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer. Answering your own question is perfectly valid. If others are looking for a solution to a similar problem, they will find your question marked as answered.

Comment: Hi Alan,  Though I have sorted of answered my initial question in a round about way, as I mentioned I am not sure why the report Builder from the portal wont now work i.e. seems to have an issue with the now corrected date.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't read to the end (my fault!)